# "Select * from <table_name>" not working from Oracle 11g when tables are created from R using 'odbc', 'DBI' package

Tags: r, oracle11g, odbc, r-dbi

I have created some tables in 'Oracle Database 11g Express Edition' using two method:

**Method-1:** From R using odbc and DBI package

```
library(odbc)
db <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                'Oracle ODBC',
                uid = "raja",
                pwd = "test123")
```

And Create a table 'cars'.

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = "cars", value = cars,
             append = T, row.names = F, overwrite = F)
```

**Method-2:** From sqlplus command prompt

```
create table my_table 
(id int not null,
 text varchar2(1000),
 primary key (id)
);

insert into my_table (id, text) values (1, 'This is some text.');
```

For verification I have run

```
SQL> select table_name from user_tables;
cars
mtcars
MY_TABLE
```

Clearly, it creates the tables.

**Now the problem is:**
When try to view/read the tables success and error comes in following pattern.

**From R:**

Success:

```
> DBI::dbReadTable(db, "cars")
```

Error:

```
> DBI::dbReadTable(db, "my_table")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "my_table"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Error:

```
> DBI::dbGetQuery(db, "select * from cars;")
Error: <SQL> 'select * from cars;'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**From sqlplus:**

Success:

```
select * from my_table;
```

Error:

```
select * from cars;
ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DBI call is using `name = "cars"`, and you can see from the query of `user_tables` that the table is being created [with a quoted-identifier name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) as that shows it as lowercase `cars`. You used an unquoted identifier for `my_table`, so that is uppercase in that query result.

As `cars` is a quoted identifier you have to quote it everywhere:

```
select * from "cars";
```

But that is a pain and no-one will thank you for using a quoted identifier (it's really better to avoid them completely unless for some reason you *have* to have a quoted name, based on the rules in the documentation linked to above); so it would be better to change your DBI call to use:

```
name = "CARS"
```

which will cause the table to be created with an unquoted identifier, meaning your original `dbGetQuery` will now work with the table name in any case - which is true any unquoted identifier (so that is why `from my_table` worked).

You will also need to change your `dbReadTable` call to also use the uppercase `"CARS"` and `"MY_TABLE"`, from the errors you are seeing.